# The intersection and sum of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I am searching for some help in the following two questions. I am made a proof for the first question, so here I am just looking to see if it is correct. In the other question I am looking for any help and tips or possibly solutions to the problem.

Let $U_1,U_2$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$ . Show the following:

(a) the intersection $U_1 ∩U_2$ := $\{~v ∈ V : ~v ∈ U_1,v ∈ U_2\}$ is a subspace

My solution:

If we let $c_1$ and $c_2$ be in the intersection of $U_1$ and $U_2$, then $c_1$ and $c_2$ is in $U_1$, any linear combo of $c_1$ and $c_2$ will then be in $U_1$. So $c_1$ and $c_2$ is also in $U_2$. Then any linear combo of $c_1$ and $c_2$ will be in $U_2$. Therefore any linear combination of $c_1$ and $c_2$ will be in the intersection of $U_1$ and $U_2$. In conclusion, the property of closure is confirmed, and the intersection of $U_1$ AND $U_2$ is a subspace of $V$

b) the sum $U1 + U2 := \{v_1 +v_2 : v_1 ∈ U_1,v_2 ∈ U2\}$ is a subspace

Looking for some help with this proof

Comment: You do the same thing. I mean what is the conclusion regarding the sum $c_1x = c_1(u_1 + u_2)$ and $c_2y = c_2(u_1' + u_2')$?

Comment: not quite sure how to work the second one out

Comment: What can you conclude about the sum I just wrote down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better you write out a full on argument with the actual vectors in part I, but other than that it is fine.

For the second question, let $x,y \in U_1 + U_2$. Now this means $$c_1x = c_1(u_1 + u_2)$$

$$c_2y = c_2(u_1' + u_2').$$

Grouping yields $c_1x + c_2y = c_1u_1 + c_2u_1' + c_1u_2+ c_2u_2' \in U_1 + U_2$ by the definition that $U_1, U_2$ are subspaces.

Comment: i will try and write it out as vectors  thanks for your help